# how to run 2 commands using a shell script

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, sh

I am writing a shell script. I want to run 2 commands. The first command is:

```
/zap.sh -daemon -config api.disablekey=true -config view.mode=attack
```

Once i run this it will listen a port (9090).

While it listen to that port I want to run a another command (a curl request)

This is how my code looks now

```
echo "start daemon";
    ~/Desktop/research/ZAP/zap.sh -daemon -config api.disablekey=true -config view.mode=attack 
    echo "deamon is running";
    a=$( curl "http://localhost:8500/JSON/spider/action/scan/?zapapiformat=JSON&url=http://localhost:8080/Danial/login&contextName=" )
```

Since the first command still running (it listen to the port) I can't go to the next command. Is there a way to do this asynchronously or some other way to do this?

Comment: Append a `&` to the first command to run it in the background.  Use `pid=$!` as a next command to collect the PID of the spawned process.  Use `kill "$pid"` to kill the spawned process when you do not need it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the first command in background, which will allow you to execute other commands while the first one is running.

Read more on this: https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/

It basically looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1 &
command2
```

Answer (score 0):

While you probably don't need anything so elaborate for this, you might peek at running a "coprocess".

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc